# Is there any way to change android:windowSoftInputMode value from ionic typescript

Tags: ionic-framework

In my Ionic application,
I am using android:windowSoftInputMode ="adjustPan" in the config file.
But I want to change android:windowSoftInputMode to "adjustResize" only for one of the screens in the app.

In short I want to set SoftInputMode programmatically on page load to "adjustResize" and change it back to "adjustPan" while leaving from the page.

Can someone help me out!